# ggplot: how to extract the time of the day from a datetime and still get a date type?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lubridate

Consider the following example

```
data <- data_frame(time = c(ymd_hms('20160201 08:10:53'),
                            ymd_hms('20160202 08:10:53'),
                            ymd_hms('20160203 08:10:54'),
                            ymd_hms('20160204 08:10:54'),
                            ymd_hms('20160205 08:10:55')),
                   value = c(1,1,1,2,2))

> data
# A tibble: 5 × 2
                 time value
               <dttm> <dbl>
1 2016-02-01 03:10:53     1
2 2016-02-02 03:10:53     1
3 2016-02-03 03:10:54     1
4 2016-02-04 03:10:54     2
5 2016-02-05 03:10:55     2
```

I want to aggregate this dataframe so that I can get the mean of `value` for at a given hour-minute-second across all days in my data.

In other words, I can do

```
> data %>%  group_by(time_agg = paste(hour(time), minute(time), second(time))) %>% 
+   summarise(mean = mean(value))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  time_agg  mean
     <chr> <dbl>
1  3 10 53   1.0
2  3 10 54   1.5
3  3 10 55   2.0
```

Here is my problem:

I need to plot this data (x axis = time, y = mean) but `time_agg` is a character! Is there a way to make R (ggplot) understand these are hours?

Comment: the `group_by` on the fly `mutate` is constructed using `paste`, which returns a character.  I would actually deconstruct the time into hours, minutes and seconds in separate columns, then group and `summarize`

Comment: thanks Jake but I dont see how your solution returns a date that `ggplot` can nicely work with.

Comment: You can then reconstruct the time from the individual `H` `M` `S` columns, then plot it.  Within `ggplot` there is `scale_x_datetime` which you should us.

Comment: Jake do you mind writing that as an answer using my simple (but working) example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a numeric column based on the `hms` as the x axis breaks and another column formatted as `%H:%M:%S` as labels to plot this in a manual way. Directly use `difftime` as x axis [is difficult](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1377):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- df %>% group_by(labels = strftime(time, "%H:%M:%S"), 
                      hours = as.numeric(as.difftime(labels))) %>% 
             summarise(mean = mean(value))
df
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: labels [?]

#    labels    hours  mean
#     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 03:10:53 3.181389   1.0
#2 03:10:54 3.181667   1.5
#3 03:10:55 3.181944   2.0

ggplot(df, aes(x = hours, y = mean)) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$hours, labels = df$labels, name = "time")
```

[image]

Comment: just a follow up. Here you `group_by` `label` and `hours` but this is just a trick right? `hours` does not vary as we change `labels`

Comment: Yes. I put both of them in `group_by` just to create two variables in the result for plotting. `hours` will correspond to the `hms` of your time column, i.e, the `labels` column.